# Laravel deny access to /public directory

Tags: laravel, public

Someone can answer me:
Is it possible in laravel to deny access to the directory inside the public folder?
I understand that everything in the public directory is public. But I need to place an folder in the /public directory and file index.html in it with some css, js, images. I need to display correctly index.html and prevent unauthorized users from viewing it.
I would be very grateful for any answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, static files inside `/public` are NOT handled by laravel, but they are served directly by your server software.

If you are using apache2, you can deny access to a public subfolder you could place an `.htaccess` file inside the directory denying access:

`public/custom/.htaccess`

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

The problem is, you would have no way to authorize access to those files outside unless you use basic auth, which is extremely basic.

---

In order to handle complex authorization and not disrupt laravel conventions, I would place those files inside a folder inside `resources` (or even `storage/app`)

```
resources
 |  custom
 |   | index.html
 |   | image.png
 |   | script.js
 |   | style.css
```

Then, in your `web.php` create a generic route for everything inside your original folder:

```
Route::get('/custom/{file?}', [CustomFilesController::class, 'getFile'])
```

Inside the controller/route you can:

- perform your authorization
- retrieve the files from the resources (or storage) folder
- serve them in response with the appropriate content type header

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! As for the directory /public, I understand that everything that is there is in the public access and the laravel does not control it. As for placing the folder in a different directory, I have already done this. For example, placed in the directory /storage. But the problem was that the files css, js and pictures were not displayed and returned a 404 error. Maybe I'm not serving the index.html file correctly.  Using the method: `File::get($path . '/index.html')`

Comment: In this way you only serve the index.html file. You should receive as input the desidered filename and return accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try setting permissions on that specific folder as per your requirement.

Simply set:

**chmod -R permission folder_path/folder_name**

You can see this link to know what combination is used for which permissions. [chmodcommand.com](https://chmodcommand.com/)